# Exception Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Using `FluentAPI` I am `autoincreamenting` the primary key of my Table.

FluentAPI configuration are as follows:

```
mb.ToTable("StationeryItems");
builder.HasKey(c => c.StationeryItemId);
```

The Exception I get:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'StationeryItems' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following, maybe they fix your problem. [`DatabaseGeneratedOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int StationeryItemId { get; set; }
```

Or:

```
builder.Entity<StationeryItems>().Property(t => t.StationeryItemId) 
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

And in EF Core:

```
builder.Entity<StationeryItems>().Property(b => b.StationeryItemId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: I need to use FluentAPI it self.

Comment: @Illep Check the second option in my updated answer.

Comment: Why can't `HasKey` handle it ?( I am a newbie. )

Comment: @Illep Key and Identity are different concepts.

Comment: So should I remove HasKey completely ?

Comment: @Illep It depends. But I think you can keep it and it doesn't hurt since identity is already unique IMO.